# Проблема с AutoField в файле models.py

Tags: python, django

```
from django.db import models

class models3D(models.Model):
     id = models.AutoField(max_length=200, db_index=True, primary_key=True)
     image = models.ImageField(upload_to='/')
     width = models.FloatField()
     height = models.FloatField()
     length = models.FloatField()
     descriptions = models.TextField(max_length=1500)
     color = models.CharField(max_length=150)
     matherials = models.CharField(max_length=1500)
     slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150)


class uploadmodel(models.Model):
     id_model = models.AutoField(db_index=True)
     link = models.SlugField(max_length=150)
     width = models.FloatField() #дописать сюда
     height = models.FloatField() #дописать сюда
     length = models.FloatField() #дописать сюда
     color =  models.CharField(max_length=150)
     matherials =  models.CharField(max_length=1500)
     descriptions = models.TextField(max_length=1500)

class users(models.Model):
     id_users = models.AutoField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
     last_name = models.CharField(max_length=1500)
     name = models.CharField(max_length=1500)
     middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=1500)
     email = models.EmailField(max_length=75)
     phone = models.FloatField() #дописать сюда
     address = models.TextField(max_length=1)

class order(models.Model):
       num_order = models.FloatField() #дописать сюда
       id_users = models.FloatField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
       id_model = models.FloatField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
       id_uploadmodel = models.FloatField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
```

ошибку выдает:

> assert not cls._meta.auto_field, "Model %s can't have more than one AutoField."
>   % cls._meta.label
>       AssertionError: Model mainpage.uploadmodel can't have more than one AutoField.

Гуглила, меняла код - все одно и то же.

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, добавьте к всякому применению метода `.AutoField()` параметр  `primary_key=True`, например к вашему первому в классе `models3D`:

```
id = models.AutoField(max_length=200, db_index=True, primary_key=True)
```

Кроме того, в конце вашего кода дважды применен метод `.AutoField()` - для `id_users` и для `id_model`:

```
class order(models.Model):
       num_order = models.FloatField() #дописать сюда
       id_users = models.AutoField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
       id_model = models.AutoField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
       id_uploadmodel = models.AutoField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
```

Это невозможно.

Comment: а что в таком случае мне нужно поставить  для id_uploadmodel?  большое спасибо

Comment: убрала AutoField, все равно пишет

Comment: Смотрите, пожалуйста, в начало моего (измененного) ответа.

Comment: поправила, все равно пишет 
    assert not cls._meta.auto_field, "Model %s can't have more than one AutoField." % cls._meta.label
AssertionError: Model mainpage.uploadmodel can't have more than one AutoField.

Comment: отредактировала пост...

Comment: вроде бы уже только один автофилд и все равно((

Comment: а, всё, спасибо огромное!

Comment: Добавите параметр `primary_key=True` k **всем** методам `.AutoField()`.

Comment: спасибо огромное вам!  А вы случайно не знаете как сделать рабочую форму регистрации на сайте с помощью пайтон, джанго?  Потому что я вроде бы сделала но оно пользователя не регистрирует, увы

Comment: Я достаточно глупый, но постепенные шаги вы можете видеть например на [этом сайте](https://www.sourcecodester.com/tutorials/python/11581/python-simple-registration-login-form-django.html). Он на английском, но код возможно понять.